# Trouble compiling "Undefined control sequence. Undefined control sequence. Too many }'s."

Tags: pdftex, compiling, overleaf

I try to create document so that the first chapter has a number, the section has no number, but each problem environment has a consecutive numbering that matches the chapter number, and the numbering starts at 1. For example:

```
Chapter 1
     Coordinate transformation
     Problem 1.1.
     Problem 1.2.
     .
     .
     .
Chapter 2 Linear Algebra
    matrices
    Problem 2.1.
    Problem 2.2.
   .
   .
   .
    SLAE solution
    Problem 2.10.
    Problem 2.11.
    .
    .
    .
Chapter 5. Integral Calculus
    Definite integral
    Problem 5.1.
    Problem 5.2.
   .
   .
   .
    Indefinite integral
    Problem 5.20.
    Problem 5.21.
   .
   .
   .
Chapter 8. Differential Equations
    Linear ODEs
    Problem 8.1.
    Problem 8.2.
   .
   .
   .
    ODE systems
    Problem 8.25.
    Problem 8.26.
   .
   .
   .
```

In this case, the problem environment for chapters 1-4 should be green, for chapters 5-7 - blue, for 8-10 - dark orange. And when I start compile this file I get the error:

**Undefined control sequence. Too many }'s."**

*My code:*

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[left=2cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% 1. Line spacing 1.15
\setstretch{1.15}

% 2. Indent margin 1.25 cm
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}

% 3. Indentation between adjacent paragraphs 12pt (double)
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}

% 6. First page title page with date and title (centered)
\title{\centering\Huge Solution Manual \endgraf\vspace{1cm}\Large \today}
\date{}
\author{Alex Milns}

% 7. Subsequent pages - content
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{14pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

% 8. Custom environment for problems
\newcounter{problem}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theproblem}{\thechapter.\arabic{problem}}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{problem}{chapter}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{problem}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{problem}%
  \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Problem \thechapter.\theproblem}%
  \par\medskip\noindent\textbf{Problem \thechapter.\theproblem: #1}\par%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white!96!gray, colframe=white!5!Green, arc=5pt, title=Solution:]
}{\end{tcolorbox}}

% Define colors for different chapter ranges
\definecolor{problemcolor1}{RGB}{75, 157, 75} % Green
\definecolor{problemcolor2}{RGB}{30, 144, 255} % Blue
\definecolor{problemcolor3}{RGB}{255, 87, 34} % Dark Orange

\newcommand{\setproblemcolor}[1]{%
  \ifnum\value{chapter}<5
    \colorlet{problemcolor}{problemcolor1}
  \else
    \ifnum\value{chapter}<8
      \colorlet{problemcolor}{problemcolor2}
    \else
      \colorlet{problemcolor}{problemcolor3}
    \fi
  \fi
}

% Apply color to problem environment
\newenvironment{customproblem}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{problem}%
  \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Problem \thechapter.\theproblem}%
  \par\medskip\noindent\textbf{Problem \thechapter.\theproblem: #1}\par%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white!96!gray, colframe=white!5!Green, arc=5pt, title=Solution:]
}{\end{tcolorbox}}

% 9. Main text font (Computer Modern)
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{concmath} % Computer Modern font

% Hyperref settings
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=magenta,
  urlcolor=cyan,
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} % Remove page number from title page

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage

\chapter{Vector algebra}
\section*{Cartesian coord}

\begin{customproblem}{Condition of the first problem}
Solution to the first problem goes here.
\end{customproblem}

\begin{customproblem}{Condition of the second problem}
Solution to the second problem goes here.
\end{customproblem}

\begin{customproblem}{Condition of the third problem}
Solution to the third problem goes here.
\end{customproblem}

\chapter{Linear Algebra}
\section*{Matrices}

\begin{customproblem}{Condition of the first problem}
Solution to the first problem goes here.
\end{customproblem}

\begin{customproblem}{Condition of the second problem}
Solution to the second problem goes here.
\end{customproblem}

\section*{SLAE solution}

\begin{customproblem}{Condition of the third problem}
Solution to the third problem goes here.
\end{customproblem}

\chapter{Integral Calculus}
\section*{Definite integral}

\begin{customproblem}{Condition of the first problem}
Solution to the first problem goes here.
\end{customproblem}

\begin{customproblem}{Condition of the second problem}
Solution to the second problem goes here.
\end{customproblem}

\section*{Indefinite integral}

\begin{customproblem}{Condition of the third problem}
Solution to the third problem goes here.
\end{customproblem}

\chapter{Differential Equations}
\section*{Linear ODEs}

\begin{customproblem}{Condition of the first problem}
Solution to the first problem goes here.
\end{customproblem}

\begin{customproblem}{Condition of the second problem}
Solution to the second problem goes here.
\end{customproblem}

\section*{ODE systems}

\begin{customproblem}{Condition of the third problem}
Solution to the third problem goes here.
\end{customproblem}

\chapter{Differential Equations}
\section*{Linear ODEs}

\begin{customproblem}{Condition of the first problem}
Solution to the first problem goes here.
\end{customproblem}

\chapter{Differential Equations}
\section*{Linear ODEs}

\begin{customproblem}{Condition of the first problem}
Solution to the first problem goes here.
\end{customproblem}

\end{document}
```

How to decide this problem?

**UPD:**

I update code, but numbering of task not correct, and the question is, is it possible to change the style of the table of contents so that there are no such gaps and write the table of contents in one line?

Comment: Instead of redefining `\problem` why don't you directly add your command to your definition of the problem environment?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

So it's work, but it's strange that I get the numbering not tight, as it should, and for example, the style of the table of contents has changed.

Comment: your example runs without giving an error so it's not possible to answer the question in the title

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  But you have several cases of `\thechapter.\theproblem` when you've already redefined `\theproblem` to include `\thechapter`.  And you define `\setproblemcolor` to take one argument, but you never use it.